# Meaning of the sentence we tend to approach problems at the product level rather than the thought that conceived it

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Would someone please explain the meaning of the sentence "we tend to approach problems at the product level rather than the thought that conceived it"

Comment: I don't think it's from a native speaker, so it only really "means" whatever we ***guess***. My guess is the speaker thinks his company should worry less about how to improve existing products, and put more effort into thinking up ***new*** products (or spend more time listening to the speaker, who thinks he's got lots of good ideas that are being ignored by his company). But mostly I'd say he's just waffling.

Answer (score 1):

This means that when they have an issue that they consider the product they are actually making, not the original idea.  This can, in turn, mean one of two things:

1. We don't let ourselves get bogged down by considering history.  The original idea is moot.  What needs to be consider is the product and how it's used.
2. We foolishly treat the decisions we made creating this product as cast in concrete, where we could fall back to the original idea behind it and realize we could achieve that best by jettison the product and making something new.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Mary, that was so nice of you..